# ElementTree instance has no attribute 'fromstring'. So, what I did wrong?

Tags: python, django, parsing, elementtree

I'm trying open and parse some html. So far, it was ok, I'm able to open the source and print it for example. But when it comes to parsing I'm stuck with "ElementTree instance has no attribute 'fromstring'"

this is my Django view.py code:

```
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
import urllib
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

def transform (request):
  opener = urllib.FancyURLopener({})
  f = opener.open("http://www.google.com/")
  r = f.read()
  f.close()
  tree = ElementTree()
  tree.fromstring(r)
  p = tree.find("body/h1")
  t = loader.get_template("transform.html")
  c = Context({'neco': p })
  return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Django Version: 1.2.4
Python Version: 2.6.5

Do anyone have some idea, please?

Answer (score 19):

Your import statement is wrong... `fromstring` is a free function in the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module, not a method of the class `xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree`:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
...
tree = etree.fromstring(r)
```

Comment: it makes sense, but now the script take the server down. not sure why.